# Strings in array are no longer strings after jQuery.each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug

I'm pretty confused with the behaviour of arrays of strings when I loop them through the `jQuery.each()` method. Apparently, the strings become jQuery objects inside the callback function. However, I cannot use the `this.get()` method to obtain the original string; doing so triggers a **this.get is not a function** error message. I suppose the reason is that it's not a DOM node. I can do `$(this).get()` but it makes my string become an array (from `"foo"` to `["f", "o", "o"]`).

How can I cast it back to string? I need to get a variable of `String` type because I pass it to other functions that compare the values among them.

I enclose a self-contained test case (requires Firebug's console):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$(function(){
    var foo = [];
    var $foo = $(foo);

    foo.push("987");
    $foo.push("987");

    foo.push("654");
    $foo.push("654");

    $.each(foo, function(i){
        console.log("foo[%d]: object=%o; value=%s; string=%o", i, this, this, $(this).get()); // this.get() does not exist
    });
    $foo.each(function(i){
        console.log("$foo[%d]: object=%o; value=%s; string=%o", i, this, this, $(this).get()); // this.get() does not exist
    });
});
//--></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just experienced the same issue, however found out that this works as expected in strict mode.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

edit/clarification: calllback functions takes two arguments, the second one is value of the variable. Use it instead of `this` 
I have tested  both variants and everything seems to work as expected (strings are still strings).

```
>>> $.each(['foo','bar'], function(i, s){ console.info( s, typeof s ) })
foo string
bar string

>>> $(['foo','bar']).each(function(i, s){ console.info( s, typeof s ) })
foo string
bar string
```

Comment: `this` is not a jQuery object when looping through strings, it wraps the string in a `String` object. If you do `this.toString()` you will get a regular string.

Answer (score 3):

This works in my Firefox 3.5:

```
$(function(){
    var foo = [];

    foo.push("abc");
    foo.push("def");

    $.each(foo, function(i){
        console.log(typeof ("" + this)); 
        });
});
```

The console shows

```
string
string
```

Comment: Hmmm... You gave me an idea: `String(this)`

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario: Sounds good :) I'm pretty much a JavaScript noob, so I tend to use the first hack that works