# JQuery.each converts string literals to Strings. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm going through the peepcode jQuery example (https://peepcode.com/products/jquery) and I chose to update all the dependencies.

Not surprisingly, I ran into an issue concerning the difference between string literals and String objects in javascript (great discussion here: [Why are there two kinds of JavaScript strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514367/why-are-there-two-kinds-of-javascript-strings))

One problem I'm hitting is that jQuery.each converts string literals to String objects, which the jQueryUI method removeClass does not handle properly. Here is a code snippet that fixes the issue.

**I'd like to know if the bug is in jQuery.each incorrectly converting string literals to String objects or should removeClass assume that it could get either a string literal or a string object.**

Update: I just realized that here's another workaround:
[Strings in array are no longer strings after jQuery.each()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522765/strings-in-array-are-no-longer-strings-after-jquery-each)

Here's the code:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    taskStates:["task-empty", "task-x", "task-apostrophe", "task-dash"],

    resetTaskStateClassNames: function() {
        var elements = this;
// Commented code breaks as "this" becomes the String object not the literal
// and removeClass does not check for String Object
//        jQuery.each(jQuery.fn.taskStates, function(){
//            elements.removeClass(this); // this is the taskState
//        })
        jQuery.fn.taskStates.forEach( function(ts) {
            elements.removeClass(ts);
        });
        return this;
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the jQuery code snippet that works. I guess the API (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)  changed since the screencast was made.

```
       jQuery.each(jQuery.fn.taskStates, function(index, value){
           elements.removeClass(value); // this is the taskState as a string literal
       })
```

Besides the fact that you can jQuery.each on either object properties or arrays, I'm don't see any advantage over simply using the javascript forEach

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with jQuery.  The value of `this` in non-strict mode is coerced to an object as if by `Object(this)`.

http://es5.github.com/#x10.4.3

> 10.4.3 Entering Function Code # Ⓣ
>
> The following steps are performed when control enters the execution context for function code contained in function object F, a caller provided thisArg, and a caller provided argumentsList:
>
> 1. If the function code is strict code, set the *ThisBinding* to *thisArg*.
> 2. Else if *thisArg* is `null` or `undefined`, set the *ThisBinding* to the global object.
> 3. **Else if *Type(thisArg)* is not *Object*, set the *ThisBinding* to `ToObject(thisArg)`.**
> 4. Else set the *ThisBinding* to *thisArg*.