# Why does running jquery each() on an array containing strings break each string into an array of the individual characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have loaded jquery and I have an array (object) containing strings like so:

```
window.stack = [
  "header",
  "nav",
  ".content",
  "footer"
];
```

When I run this through a loop using jquery's each() function and try to get each of my strings back again like this:

```
$.each(window.stack,function(){
    var h = this;
    console.log(h);
})
```

...I get this:

```
String [ "h", "e", "a", "d", "e", "r" ]
String [ "n", "a", "v" ]
String [ ".", "c", "o", "n", "t", "e", "n", "t" ]
String [ "f", "o", "o", "t", "e", "r" ]
```

Why don't I just get:

```
header
nav
.content
footer
```

?

Comment: This question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522765/strings-in-array-are-no-longer-strings-after-jquery-each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$.each(window.stack, function(key, value)`.

From http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

> The value can also be accessed through the this keyword, but Javascript will always wrap the this value as an Object even if it is a simple string or number value.

So, if you want to use `this`,

```
$.each(window.stack,function(){
 var h = this;
 console.log(h.toString());
})
```

Comment: "Javascript will always wrap the this value as an Object even if it is a simple string or number value" <-- That's the answer right there, I didn't get this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
  $.each(window.stack,function(key,value){

    console.log(value);
})
```